# Problems creating a full text index on a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-indexing

I have a view which has been created like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwData] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  [DataField1] ,
            [DataField2] ,
            [DataField3]
    FROM    dbo.tblData
```

When I try to create a full text index on it, like this:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[vwData](
[DataField] LANGUAGE [English])
KEY INDEX [idx_DataField]ON ([ft_cat_Server], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM)
```

I get this error:

```
View 'dbo.vwData' is not an indexed view. 
Full-text index is not allowed to be created on it.
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have to make your view indexed by creating unique clustered index:

```
create unique clustered index ix_vwData on vwData(<unique columns>)
```

After that, index `idx_DataField` must be a unique, non-nullable, single-column index.

Answer (score 20):

First you need to create a unique clustered index on a view, before creating a fulltext index.

Suppose you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblData](
    [DataField1] [Varchar] NOT NULL,
    [DataField2] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [DataField3] [varchar](10) NULL
    )
```

And as you already did, you have a view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwData] 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  [DataField1] ,
            [DataField2] ,
            [DataField3]
    FROM    dbo.tblData
GO
```

Now you need to create unique clustered index on a view :

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_DataField
    ON [dbo].[vwData] (DataField1);
GO
```

After the unique key is created since you already have fulltext catalog **ft_cat_Server** you can create a fulltext index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[vwData](
[DataField1] LANGUAGE [English])
KEY INDEX [idx_DataField]ON ([ft_cat_Server], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM)
```

Hope this helps :)